# How To Add Firebase Firestore Document Auto Generated ID Add In Collection Custom Data Field In React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna like this example in my project. See example
[image]

But when i implement this example by react js i can't do this . See my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('stack_over')

    const id = firebase.firestore().collection('stack_over').doc().id

    this.state = {
        question_id: id,
        question_title: '',
    };
}
onSubmitData = (e) => { 
 e.preventDefault() 
 const { question_id, question_title } = this.state; 
 this.ref.add({ question_id, question_title })
 .then((docRef) => { 
 this.setState({ question_id:'', question_title:'' }) }).catch((error) => { console.error("", error) }) }
```

I would like to do this when i insert new data then auto generated document id inserted question_id field . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const id = firebase.firestore().collection('stack_over').doc().id
```

will give you an auto generated id, but if you want to add data to the database then you need to use `set()`:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('stack_over').doc(id).set({
        question_id: id,
        question_title: 'title',
    }).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
   })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
   });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: onSubmitData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
const {
            question_id, question_title
        } = this.state;

        this.ref.add({
           question_id, question_title
        }).then((docRef) => {
            this.setState({
                question_id:'',
question_title:''
            })
            
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("", error)
            })
    }